# Applying Drools decision tables to 1-n data structures

Tags: drools

I have the following classes, where there's a 1 - n relationship between Customer and Order, i.e. each Customer has many Orders

```
class Customer {
    string identifier;
    string country;
    Collection orders;
}
class Order {
    string identifier;
    float amount;
}
class Report {
    string identifier;
    string country;
    float amount;
}
```

I want to write the following in the form of one or more Drools decision tables.

```
For each Customer c
    if c.country == US then
        for each Order o
            if o.amount > $10 then
                create Report r
                r.country = c.country
                r.amount = o.amount
```

How possible is this using Drools decision tables?

When a Customer object meets the Customer condition, I then need to run each instance in the collection of Orders through the Order condition. If the order meets the condition, I need to create a report object that has values taken from the Customer and from the Order.

Answer (score 1):

Drools will naturally iterate through collections.

This what your rule would look like in DRL:

```
rule "US Customer - Create Reports"
when
  $customer: Customer( country == "US", $orders: orders != null )
  $order: Order( amount > 10 ) from $orders
then
  Report r = new Report();
  r.country = $customer.country;
  r.amount = $order.amount;
  // TODO: do something with Report r here
end
```

This flattens naturally into a decision table in a very straight-forward fashion. You can even sub out the `"US"` (country) and `10` (amount) to variables.

Comment: Many thanks for confirming this. I'm planning on implementing this using Data frames. Can this example be implemented using data frames (Customer, Order)?